# Reports are not getting generated in Newman when any one test fails

Tags: postman, newman

When any one request of a Postman collection fails, reports are not getting generated in Newman. Execution will end showing error containing text "response.toJSON"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue can be resolved by making below changes:

1. Open the HTML file (path: `npm\node_modules\newman\lib\reporters\html`)
2. Comment the line `reducedExecution.response = reducedExecution.response.toJSON();`
3. Save the file and re-execute the script.

That's it!